# spring boot 2 with elasticsearch 2.4 via spring data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have a spring boot 1.5.9 application that connects to an elasticsearch 2.4.0 instance using spring-data-elasticsearch (2.1.3). Now I need to upgrade spring boot to version 2 to make it work with a new dependency.

If I take the latest spring boot version (2.1.0), it comes with spring-data-elasticsearch 3.1.2 which uses elasticsearch 6.4.2. But according to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch I should use spring-data-elasticsearch 2.1.x so I specified the versions as follows:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.6</version>
</dependency>
```

But now I get the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'partSearchRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1239)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:515)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:750)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:383)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:248)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:191)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:85)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$4(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:295)
at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:295)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:67)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741)
... 52 more
```

where the partSearchRepository is defined as:

```
public interface PartSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Part, Long> {
}
```

From this I gather that spring-data-elasticsearch (see `ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet()`) doesn't work well with the newer spring-data-commons.

Is there a way to use spring boot 2 with elasticsearch 2.4 then?

Comment: No. Because newer spring boot requires Spring 5.1 and the version of Spring Data ElasticSearch you are using isn't compatible with that. So no there isn't.

Comment: Why not posting that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot 2.1, requires Spring 5.1 . The Spring Data ElasticSearch version you are using is bound to Spring 4, so that is not going to work.

The short answer thus is no you cannot.